# Error converting string list to list when it contains 'inf'

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to convert this string to a list:

```
x ='[(6167.473999999997, inf), (9442.406000000004, 9527.590999999999), (12130.588999999996, 12548.22100000001), (10461.183000000006, 10669.501999999999), (53711.67000000004, 53805.396000000015), (9295.464999999997, 8816.614999999998), (12636.802000000005, 12378.355999999996)]'
```

I tried using `ast.literal_eval(x)` and `eval(x)` but both give me an error. When using the `ast` method I get: `ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x7f3a27bacb10>` and when using the `eval()` method I get: `NameError: name 'inf' is not defined`. I understand the cause of the errors, but I don't know how to solve them.

How can I solve these errors?

Comment: Python doesn't have a literal for infinity.

Comment: You'll probably need `NumPy` to handle the `inf`

Comment: https://lwn.net/Articles/833624/

Comment: Rather than trying to convert this string, find what created the string in the first place and change that to use a proper serialization format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inf` is not valid ...

I guess you could replace it

```
ast.literal_eval(x.replace('inf','float("inf")'))
```

but that breaks because you cannot literal_eval a function call

you can use eval ... but thats more dangerous

```
eval(x.replace('inf','float("inf")'))
```

or you can use a number that will get translated to inf

```
ast.literal_eval(x.replace('inf','2e308'))  # will result in a python `inf`


>>> print(ast.literal_eval('2e308'))
inf
```

[warning] the last option is likely implementation dependent and may not work for all versions of python, and it may break in a future python release

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the best way I think is indeed to replace inf with a number!

Comment: a word of warning this is likely implementation specific and may break in future versions of python